# USB code for Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, usb

I want to use usb in my application to retrieve data from my computer (present in text files) to android mobile and read it... what are the neccessities in terms of hardware and helpful links for the usb code...

Recently google launched USB accessory for android 2.3 ... it have classes UsbManager, UsbAccessory etc... i want to use that ... how can it be used.??

Answer (score 0):

Usually the opposite of this is observed, where the android mobile projects itself as a usb device (client) , The USB host controller driver on the computer recognizes the device and handles future USB requests from your client. This is just the hardware layer, mind you. Since the USB protocol has become so ubiquitous, the computer actually stores multiple families of drivers both at the kernel layer and user space to be able to handle the variety of requests and their user space interpretations.

Since android mobiles are primarily linux-based devices, to achieve your end you will need to integrate these USB host-based driver families to your device's kernel / ROM. You will need to create a custom ROM (someone else asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232620/getting-started-with-creating-custom-roms)). [This link](http://www.linux-usb.org/devices.html) provides you a list of drivers corresponding to specific hardware families.

Additionally, you will need to set up necessary programs on your computer that allows it to project itself as a USB client.

If you use linux on the computer too, [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7353) might help you to start.